# how to remove or disable the extra column and row selection function?

Tags: c#, winforms, devexpress, xtragrid

I have grid view, and I have already disable the column auto width so I can manually set the size of column. after manually resize there's a  extra blank column. and what I want is :

1. To disable the select row function when i click on outside of the column in Active, code and generate
2. Remove the extra column.

[image: grid view]

I already success fully hide the remaining column with this event or code

```
  private void gridView1_CustomDrawColumnHeader(object sender, ColumnHeaderCustomDrawEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Column == null)
        {
            e.Handled = true;

        }
    }
```

The thing is I still can click on the outside of the genre, and the row selection still follow where I click

[image: grid 2]

Comment: iam using this code to hide. but the thing is i can still click it and the row selection still enable
` private void gridView1_CustomDrawColumnHeader(object sender, ColumnHeaderCustomDrawEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Column == null)
            {
                e.Handled = true;
                
            }
        }'
i thought if there is another way to remove the xtra column

Comment: my bad !
any idea how to solve?

Comment: The first question should be: where does the extra column come from and do you really want to have it? If you don't want it you have to decide if you want to show the (by default darkgray) background or want to resize a column or want to resize the DGV as a whole.. As for keeping it and still only select inside the first three columns: Set SelectionMode to RowHeader and code the cellclicked event to do the selections you want..

Comment: the extra column comes from i am manully resize the column and disable the auto column width which lead to extra column maybe because i dont use full column in the view. and i dontwant it.
want it but need to disable the click row slection

Comment: Sorry, but maybe I got the control wrong: Are we talking about Winforms `DataGridView` or about a different control? (You tagged it `GridView`).. In a `DataGridview` __no extra columns__ get shown when you resize columns, just extra space without any headers and clicking into the extra space wil __not__ select a row, no matter which `SelectionMode`!

Comment: @ShakirAhamed Thanks for editing grammar and spelling. Based on `ColumnHeaderCustomDrawEventArgs` the control which is used in the question is a devexpress xtragrid. Removing those tags may cause someone thing it's datagridview and waste someone's time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Handle the [GridView.MouseDown](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraGridViewsBaseBaseView_MouseDowntopic) event in the following way:

```
private void gridView1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e) {
    GridView view = (GridView)sender;
    var hi = view.CalcHitInfo(e.Location);
    Console.WriteLine(hi.HitTest);
    if (hi.InRow && !hi.InRowCell)
        DXMouseEventArgs.GetMouseArgs(e).Handled = true;
}
```

Comment: work perfectly fine.
but kinda dont what each code do.. its new to me
can u kindly explain it?

Comment: Selection occurs on the mouse events in the grid. So, we handle the first mouse event (MouseDown), check what area we click. If it's an empty area (the grid hit info will tell that you click in a row, but not in a cell), we stop further processing this event by the grid by the DXMouseEventArgs.GetMouseArgs(e).Handled = true line.

Comment: thats what confuse me, why e.handle true = disable the mouse event, if false click.
thanks for the explanation